# Convert .gprobs files from Impute2 to PLINK format

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, imputation, genome

I have some imputed .gprobs files (one per chromosome), imputed by Impute2 downloaded from dbGaP, and I need to convert this file into .bed format of PLINK in order to do some analysis.

My .gprobs files look like:

```
--- rs371609562:61395:CTT:C 61395 CTT C 0 0.023 0.977 0 0.039 0.961 0 0.015 0.985 0 0.026 0.974 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Could someone help me find out how convert this kind of file into PLINK format? Or guide me about which files I need to perform the convertion?

P.D.: I know that this question maybe shouldn't be here, but I didn't know any other place to ask about it.

Comment: I replied below. but you make get more replies on www.biostars.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `.gprobs` it appears you mean **Oxford format**, see:

https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats#gen

If this is correct then plink can read in this format as described here:

https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/input#oxford

In the same command you can output to PLINK binary format:

```
plink --gen file.gen --sample file.sample --make-bed --out output_prefix
```

Note following caveat regarding converting Oxford to PLINK:

> Since the PLINK 1 binary format cannot represent genotype
>   probabilities, calls with uncertainty greater than 0.1 are normally
>   treated as missing, and the rest are treated as hard calls. You can
>   adjust this threshold by providing a numeric parameter to
>   --hard-call-threshold.
>
> Alternatively, when --hard-call-threshold is given the 'random'
>   modifier, calls are independently randomized according to the
>   probabilities in the file. (This is not ideal; it would be better to
>   randomize in a haploblock-sensitive manner. But resampling a bunch of
>   times with this and generating an empirical distribution of some
>   statistic can still be more informative than applying a single
>   threshold and calculating that statistic once.)

*Source: https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/input#oxford*

Comment: I've tried the following code:

    `plink --gen file_chr10.gprobs.gz --sample file.sample --oxford-single-chr 10 --make-bed --out output`

It started converting variants, but then it gave an error:

    `Error: File read failure.`

And I don´t know why it gives this error.

I think it could be because I didn't extract the sample.gz file, because it gives me an error, instead I did `less file.sample.gz > file.sample`
Any lead about how to extract the file.sample.gz properly?

Comment: You likely need to extract `.gprobs` file. `gunzip -c file_chr10.gprobs.gz > file_chr10.gen`.